# Volley Library - Application crashes due to slow requests

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm having an application crashes due to slow requests.
Im request a json called "result" for my login.

```
myRequest.AuthenticationRequest(username,password,getApplicationContext());

    final Handler handlerC = new Handler();
    handlerC.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String result = myRequest.getResult();
            if(result.equals("success"))
            {
                userInfoHolder.setSESSION(username);
                userInfoHolder.RequestUserInfo(getApplicationContext());
                userInfoHolder.RequestUserOtherInfo(getApplication());
                final Handler handlerC = new Handler();
                handlerC.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,User.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, 500);

 public void AuthenticationRequest(final String username, final String password,Context c)
{
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(c);
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, controllerLinks.getUrlLogin(), new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                setResult(jsonObject.getString("result"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {@Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}}){ @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>(){
                {
                    put("login","clicked");
                    put("username",username);
                    put("password",password);
                }
            };
            return hashMap;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

I tried to fix my problem by using postDelayed but I think there is a better way to handle the problem, I just don't have an idea how to do it, please help.

```
01-11 13:46:34.606 3697-3697/com.example.a1412.alzhaid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.a1412.alzhaid, PID: 3697
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.a1412.alzhaid.Home$5.run(Home.java:252)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: It's happening at Line 252 of your `Home` class and it's caused by the following: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Nerd, yeah it is getting null values because the request is slow, is there an "On success" or something like that in volley library?

Comment: I believe its happening because you're getting the result on one thread (Volley's) and comparing it in another (your Handler). That's not the right way to do it. Either compare values when you get them (when you setResult) or have a callback mechanism, which will make sure that compare is called only after you've received the data.

Comment: Would you mind if i'll ask an example of those 2? I don't really have an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have NullPointerException in this section:

String result = myRequest.getResult();
if(result.equals("success")) .....

Please check your args.
I suggest you use Retrofit

Retrofit is a REST client for Android, through which you can make easy to use interface while Volley is a networking library.

Retrofit is a lot easier to configure. With Volley, if the default HurlStack isn’t enough for you, good luck! Most average developers will struggle to configure Volley, luckily there is a lot of code they can copy paste but even then, they may not know what they are doing.

Volley will handle avoiding duplicate calls, not sure if Retrofit will.

Volley provides network image handling support.

Volley can integrate with most popular HTTP clients out there that include OkHttp where as Retrofit (as far as I know) relies on OkHttp.

Retrofit remains up to date. Volley may be relying on a library bundled with your OS, hence updating the network client isn’t an option.

Retrofit makes it much easier to configure HTTP intercepts (if you want to do something before or after an HTTP call)

Volley can provide fine grain control over caching strategy, but its harder to configure caching than Retrofit.

Retrofit relies on OkHttp, which relies on Okio which effectively makes this library huge compared to a basic configuration of Volley. If size is an issue, Volley is a better bet.

use this linke for more information:
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/is-retrofit-faster-than-volley-the-answer-may-surprise-you-4379bc589d7c